# How to DM all members of a guild

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

Would like to DM every member on a guild but no idea how to do so.

The following doesn't work:

```
message.guild.members.get().send("Test")
```

Comment: Well it wouldn't be that easy.. You need to go through each member, then send a DM individually to each one. And you can't do it in one take, or you would be rate-limited.

Comment: You can get list of members (array) and then using loop send to each member

Comment: And how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through every single member and privately messages them individually - make sure to use the setTimeout() function to have a 1-2 second interval between DM's otherwise you might get rate-limited.

I would get the list of the member's id and then dm each one using the .forEach() function. So something like this:

```js
message.channel.guild.members.forEach(user => {
    user.send(content);
});
```

By the way, keep in mind that some people only allow friends to private message them so make sure to handle that.

Comment: `guild.members` is a collector. And `forEach` is for arrays not collectors.
Change the `forEach` to an `every`